# Android library to load multiple image from server, pan, zoom and rotate

Tags: android, zooming, picasso

In my project, there is a activity where I need to load 2/3 images from server in a image view. Then need to do the below operation with them:
Paging, zooming and rotation by touch gesture. 
I have searched a lot but could not manage to find any suitable library for those options.

I tried to achieve it by combining libraries( Picasso +others) but could not manage.

Please guide my to achieve this. 
Any sample code, library reference or tutorial will be better.

Answer (score 1):

[TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

which helps to zoom the image

Comment: Any suggestion about rotation?

Comment: @RuhulAmin There is this cool library: https://github.com/Almeros/android-gesture-detectors , but it's BSD license. I don't understand what BSD license means (I've tried to read about it, and English isn't my main language, so I failed to understand). Does it mean whatever I do with the library, I can't make a closed source app of it? Or change the code?

Answer (score 0):

I really like Volley for working with image downloads. It offers a class called "NetworkImageView" which allows you to give it a URL and it loads the image directly, and even scales it down if needed.

As for your zoom & rotation gestures, have a look at uk.co.senab.PhotoView - it's a class which extends ImageView (you can change it to extend NetworkImageView), and allows touch interactions such as zoom. I'm not sure if it supports rotation, but I'm sure that once you get familiar with it, you can add this functionality.

Volley: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

PhotoView: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView